# "No module named yum" centos7

Tags: python, yum

my OS is CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708

First,I install anaconda for python.then I replace the default python in /usr/bin/python.

```
$ ll /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  7 Aug 15 03:40 /usr/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Aug  9 22:10 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Aug  9 22:10 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> /root/anaconda2/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Aug  9 21:59 /usr/bin/python3.6 -> /root/anaconda3/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Aug  8 23:49 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7


Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

so I can't use yum any more.

```
$ yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55)
[GCC 7.2.0]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I'm try to fix `vi /usr/bin/yum` the first line to any other python path.
but it doesn't work.

also,I'm trying to reinstall python*.rpm like this:

```
rpm -ivh python-tools-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm python-libs-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm tkinter-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

and reinstall `yum*.rpm` (I download a lot of `*.rpm` today...)
but, still not work. 
anyone give me a hand? thanks!

Comment: Here is the solution to related problem
[enter link description here](https://superuser.com/a/662288)

Comment: Here is the solution: ["No module named yum” centos7](https://superuser.com/a/662288)

Comment: Try reinstall Python package with `--force` option.

Comment: @Zalatik how to reinstall Python package using --force ？

Comment: @YiLevin `rpm -ivh --force python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: yes, it works,yeah... thank you, I try a lot of things to fix it. and now it's done, but I still don't know the theory.

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem on CentOS7 with Yum3.4.3, Python2.7.5 recently,

> [root@centos64b build]# yum list There was a problem importing
> one of the Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to
> this problem was:
>
> No module named yum
>
> Please install a package which provides this module, or verify that
> the module is installed correctly.
>
> It's possible that the above module doesn't match the current version
> of Python, which is:
> 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]
>
> If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to  the yum faq
> at:   http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

While I did not update Python before I met this problem. Finally it is found that python site-packages libpath was not set in sys.path, so the fix here is to append the site-package libpath to sys.path in /usr/bin/yum Python script. Then yum works fine.

```sh
[build@centos64b ~]$ more /usr/bin/yum
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Comment: Thanks! You made my day! Also I added these lines into `/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down`

Answer (score 0):

I found two solution for the problem on *Superuser* [StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/661983/no-module-named-yum-after-yum-update/662288#662288)

### Solution 1

- ln -s /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum/yum.conf

### Solution 2

Remove newly installed python

- rm /usr/bin/python

Link python with the correct version (x.y)

- ln -s /usr/bin/python**x.y** /usr/bin/python

Comment: but I can't find the old python, all the /usr/bin/python* is I installed , the default pythonx.y was remove.

Comment: Whichever version is present, try to link it using the ln command. & also to fix yum, you'll need to edit  /etc/yum/yum.conf

Comment: how to link? please help me,
my python2.6 is ``/usr/local/bin/python``
my python2.7 is `` /usr/bin/python``
but the default python is python2.6.
and also, I don't know how to fix yum 
the content is here.
```vi /etc/yum/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
```

Comment: Cn you sare output of the  following command `ls -l /usr/bin pyth*` and `ls -l /usr/local/bin pyth*`

Comment: Most probably, following two commands shhould fix your problem, ` rm /usr/bin/python; ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall `python` with

```
rpm -ivh --force python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Why it works. Generally rpm is tolerant to files of other packages. In your case it sees that it didn't create the link files so it skipped them on install. From [`man rpm`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm)
we can find

```
--force
    Same as using --replacepkgs, --replacefiles, and --oldpackage. 
--replacefiles
    Install the packages even if they replace files from other, already installed, packages.
```

With these options `rpm` does not care about the fact, that old files were created by someone else.

P.S. Some tips: never remove change files in `/usr/bin`. `/bin` is better place for your links. Even better add your `bin` directory to `$PATH` by adding to your `.bash_profile` something like this:

```
$PATH=/root/anaconda2/bin/python2.7:$PATH
```

So if something breaks, it's just a matter of removing the line from `.bash_profile`.
And once more: always do backups, especially when working with system files.